# Exportar archivo Excel con fecha a Xml

Tags: excel, xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Muy buenas, tengo una hoja de Excel que necesito exportar a Xml, he creado el archivo "Base" xml con las cabeceras del excel, he habilitado el modo Developer, he emparejado el archivo con la estructura xml y esta ahi todo bien. El problema me surge al exportar el Excel a xml que me da un error por compatibilidad con las fechas.
Decir que si, me exporta el archivo pero en el campo fecha me pone unos numero que no tienen mucho que ver con la fecha.

EL mensaje en ingles que me da cuando intento emparejar es:
**The data that you are attempting to map contains formatting that is incompatible  with the format specified in the worksheet**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excel almanacea fechas como integer desde 1-Ene-1900 y tiempo despues del decimal.  Por ejemplo 8-Abr-2020 almanacea como 43929 por que 8-Abr-2020 es 43929 dias despues de 1-Ene-1900.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, no le encontraba sentido a ese número que me sale.Necesito exportar a xml para hacer transferencias a un banco, no tengo claro si el banco acepta la fecha de esa forma.

Comment: @LorenzoMartín prueba a añadir una comilla simple antes de la fecha. Es decir, si el valor de la celda es, por ejemplo, `31/12/2020`, hazlo que sea `'31/12/2020` (fíjate que puse `'` al principio. A ver si así te lo coge

Comment: La comilla simple me ha valido, muchas gracias. Si puedes, ponlo como una respuesta para darla por valida

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar el formato de las columnas que contengan fecha a formato "texto". Selecciona toda la columna, botón derecho, formato de celda, texto.
Por defecto excel tiene formato "general" y si detecta una fecha la convierte, como dice Duston, a integer.
El xml es en sí mismo un fichero de texto, por lo que no debería de darte error a la hora de enviarlo al banco, a no ser que el formato de la fecha que espera el banco no sea correcto.